# How to build a matrix out of an matrix by column index?

Tags: python

My question is a title bit unusual.

I have an nxn matrix M  and an tuple P with arbitrary tuple size. Each element of those tuples is an index of the columns of the matrix M. The coal is to create a matrix with unknown tuple size.

With known tuple size its easy for example tuple size 2.

> [list(M[:][P[0]]),list(M[:][P[1]])]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used `numpy` because of matrix operations

```
import numpy as np 

P = [0,2,1]
mat = np.array([[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [5,5,5]])
row, col = mat.shape
print(row, col)
new_mat = np.array([])

for index in P:
    if index < col:
        new_mat = np.append(new_mat, mat[:, index], axis=0)
        print(mat[:, index], new_mat)
    else:
        print("ERROR...")
new_mat = np.reshape(new_mat, (row, col))
print(new_mat)
```

Output:

```
[[1. 2. 5.]
 [3. 4. 5.]
 [2. 3. 5.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily make a list out of tuple:

```py
>>> a = (1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> list(a)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

You can then iterate over the created list, appending selected columns to result matrix.

Or you can do it in one line, with:

```py
[M[:][column_numer] for column_number in list(P)]
```

You can also make an iterable out of tuple with `iter(P)`

Answer (score 0):

Using `numpy`， one line of code made it.

```
P = (1,2,3)
import numpy as np
M = np.random.rand(5, 5)
M
```

Output:

```
array([[0.93352672, 0.06928974, 0.17257714, 0.08542694, 0.15506198],
       [0.13822767, 0.79759968, 0.10856181, 0.81628828, 0.85438494],
       [0.08275138, 0.39263782, 0.61261336, 0.96710702, 0.77384262],
       [0.50015147, 0.81396183, 0.14529028, 0.38635101, 0.37187102],
       [0.78103983, 0.28536907, 0.18966005, 0.98560228, 0.15319965]])
```

Then:

```
M[P, :].tolist()
```

Output:

```
[[0.13822767112825451,
  0.7975996819335665,
  0.10856180650935543,
  0.8162882788520752,
  0.8543849360373945],
 [0.08275137683298706,
  0.39263782093712707,
  0.6126133556050365,
  0.9671070232785762,
  0.7738426182905598],
 [0.5001514657386527,
  0.8139618306741762,
  0.1452902780548645,
  0.3863510083602032,
  0.37187101844695913]]
```